# Customised ABI in Linux Kernel 2.6.11 boot code

Tags: assembly, gcc, linux-kernel, x86, abi

Recently I have tried to read the code of Linux Kernel 2.6.11. In the path `arch/x86/boot/` I found  some codes about jumping to protected mode. I did not understand what ABI did they use and where did they declare the ABI.

The declaration of `protected_mode_jump`

```c
/* pmjump.S */
void __attribute__((noreturn))
    protected_mode_jump(u32 entrypoint, u32 bootparams);
```

The usage of `protected_mode_jump`

```c
/*
 * Actual invocation sequence
 */
void go_to_protected_mode(void)
{
    /* Hook before leaving real mode, also disables interrupts */
    realmode_switch_hook();

    /* Move the kernel/setup to their final resting places */
    move_kernel_around();

    /* Enable the A20 gate */
    if (enable_a20()) {
        puts("A20 gate not responding, unable to boot...\n");
        die();
    }

    /* Reset coprocessor (IGNNE#) */
    reset_coprocessor();

    /* Mask all interrupts in the PIC */
    mask_all_interrupts();

    /* Actual transition to protected mode... */
    setup_idt();
    setup_gdt();
    protected_mode_jump(boot_params.hdr.code32_start,
                (u32)&boot_params + (ds() << 4));
}
```

The define of `protected_mode_jump`

```
 
/*
 * The actual transition into protected mode
 */

#include <asm/boot.h>
#include <asm/processor-flags.h>
#include <asm/segment.h>

    .text

    .globl  protected_mode_jump
    .type   protected_mode_jump, @function

    .code16

/*
 * void protected_mode_jump(u32 entrypoint, u32 bootparams);
 */
protected_mode_jump:
    movl    %edx, %esi      # Pointer to boot_params table

    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    movw    %cs, %bx
    shll    $4, %ebx
    addl    %ebx, 2f
    jmp 1f          # Short jump to serialize on 386/486
1:

    movw    $__BOOT_DS, %cx
    movw    $__BOOT_TSS, %di

    movl    %cr0, %edx
    orb $X86_CR0_PE, %dl    # Protected mode
    movl    %edx, %cr0

    # Transition to 32-bit mode
    .byte   0x66, 0xea      # ljmpl opcode
2:  .long   in_pm32         # offset
    .word   __BOOT_CS       # segment

    .size   protected_mode_jump, .-protected_mode_jump

    .code32
    .type   in_pm32, @function
in_pm32:
    # Set up data segments for flat 32-bit mode
    movl    %ecx, %ds
    movl    %ecx, %es
    movl    %ecx, %fs
    movl    %ecx, %gs
    movl    %ecx, %ss
    # The 32-bit code sets up its own stack, but this way we do have
    # a valid stack if some debugging hack wants to use it.
    addl    %ebx, %esp

    # Set up TR to make Intel VT happy
    ltr %di

    # Clear registers to allow for future extensions to the
    # 32-bit boot protocol
    xorl    %ecx, %ecx
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    xorl    %ebx, %ebx
    xorl    %ebp, %ebp
    xorl    %edi, %edi

    # Set up LDTR to make Intel VT happy
    lldt    %cx

    jmpl    *%eax           # Jump to the 32-bit entrypoint

    .size   in_pm32, .-in_pm32
```

I know that we can choose not to use standard Linux ABI and switch another one through declaring the function attribute `__attribute__`. But as the code shown above, the function `protected_mode_jump` only declared `__attribute__((noreturn))`, which no modify the ABI. And I did not find where the code declared the ABI and which kind of ABI it used after I browsing the `Makefile` and searching under the path using `grep`. So could anyone help me find out it?

Comment: What ABI are you talking about? And what is the problem with the code shown? Why do you want to "change  ABI"? Why do you think that ABI is "Customed"?

Comment: Try explaining your question without relying on the term ABI which seems to be producing some amount of confusion.

Comment: @0___________ In the definition of `protected_mode_jump`, they do not pass the function parameters through the stack but through the EAX and EDX registers. If it uses the standard Linux ABI of i386, it should access the function parameters by using stack.

Comment: @PollardLee 2.6.11 was released 18y ago. Why are you analyzing it?

Comment: @teapot418 OK, I mean the way they pass the function parameters. I know the way that passing parameters and the switching context is a convention that the callee and caller agree on. But in the usual way, in i386, we pass the function parameters by using the stack right? However in this code, the function `protected_mode_jump` does not pass the function parameters through the stack but uses registers EAX and EDX. It is not the usual call convention. I wonder where the code tell the compiler to generate code in the convention it wants.

Comment: It used to be that the GCC `-mregparm=3` option was used to compile kernel code which had the effect of passing the first 3 parameters in registers rather than the stack (unlike the normal 32-bit System V ABI). The parameters were passed in these registers (in this order): EAX, EDX, and ECX. This is documented here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Function-Attributes.html . I believe you will find the `-mregparm=3` option being passed to the GCC command line via the Makefiles.

Comment: @0___________ just for studying it. I am reading the book ~~ Understanding the Linux kernel~~ now. It explains the kernel 2.6.11 so I chose this version to study. Actually I am a linux kernel newbie

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you, Michael. I noticed the `regparm` in the manual before. But I thought it is only used in the `__attribute__()` by mistake. I will look at it again and carefully.

Comment: @MichaelPetch you could make that comment an answer (or maybe we should close as dupe? unsure)